# vim/gvim freezes when shelling out, how to trace events?

Tags: shell

NOTE: This underlying problem was solved by an update of Cygwin
packages and re-install of `vim`.  However, the question of how to
trace errors in shelling out remains, so answers along that front
would be appreciated.

I use Cygwin's 64-bit installation on Windows 10 Pro (64-bit), including X-windows and `vim`/`gvim`.  In all the installs I've done this year, I get the following message:

** (gvim:2221): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.free desktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus with out replying

I've successfully ignored it until now.  On a brand new installation
yesterday, however, when I shell out from `gvim`, it freezes.  The task
manager shows 20% CPU usage due to `gvim`, and I assume that its fully
using 1 of 4 cores (i5-8365U).  This is observed from a
non-administrator account.  Oddly, if I do the same thing from an
administrator account, it still freezes, but there is no CPU usage.  I
make sure that I remove the following X-windows files from the
non-administrator account before switching to test from the
administrator account:

```
rm -rf ~/.serverauth.* /tmp/.X0-lock /tmp/.X11-unix /var/log/xwin/XWin.0.log
```

Issuing `kill` from a bash shell doesn't banish the window, and neither does ending the task from Task Manager (with and without elevated privileges).  If I exit the `xterm` from which `gvim` was issued, however, the unresponsive `gvim` process and window goes away.

I don't like doing this, however, as the current X-windows installation doesn't give me an option to launch a new `xterm`.  I need to shut down X-windows, then start it again.

I've included `vim/gvim` in the question because I'm not sure where the problem occurs.  The problem only shows with I use `gvim`, but I can't necessarily blame `gvim`.  This is because I have one `vimrc` for both, and it checks whether it is being run from Windows compilation or a cygwin compilation, and also checks whether it is `vim` or `gvim`.  Some of the code differs depending on these checks.  Having everything in one file is a net benefit, however, because I have a lot of common setup code.   It means, however, that the cause of the crash could very well be due to different control flow in my `vimrc` rather than Cygwin's `gvim`.

Is there a way to turn on verbose messaging so that I can see what is happening when I shell out?

Is there another way to trace the events that might cause this crash?

I usually shell out in one of 2 ways:

**1.** In normal mode, double-bang (!!) followed by a bash command, e.g., `!!ls`

**2.** In the `:` command line, starting with a bang (!), optionally preceded by a line range.

**Attempted Troubleshooting**

- `:set verbose` doesn't help, because I'm shelling out rather than calling `vim` scripts
- If I start `gvim -u NONE -U NONE`, then `:scriptnames` shows only following and attempts to shell out no longer freeze gvim:

  1: /usr/share/vim/vim82/menu.vim 
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim82/autoload/paste.vim
- However, a normal mode like `!!ls` doesn't import the results of
  the `ls` command either.  It merely results in the message `Command terminated`.  ***It would be nice to be able to trace the cause of
  this.***
- If I right-click the X-windows server on the system tray, I have to
  option of view the log file `/var/log/xwin/XWin.0.log` (Annex
  below)....

**Annex: /var/log/xwin/XWin.0.log**

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.20.5.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-18362 ___-____-___-__ 3.1.5-340.x86_64 2020-06-01 08:59 UTC x86_64
OS: Windows 10  [Windows NT 10.0 build 18362] (Win64)
Package: version 1.20.5-3 built 2019-09-06

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -auth 
 /home/User.Name/.serverauth.1210 

ddxProcessArgument - Initializing default screens
winInitializeScreenDefaults - primary monitor w 1920 h 1080
winInitializeScreenDefaults - native DPI x 144 y 144
[   845.234] (II) xorg.conf is not supported
[   845.234] (II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
[   845.234] LoadPreferences: /home/User.Name/.XWinrc not found
[   845.234] LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
[   845.250] LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
[   845.250] winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
[   845.296] winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
[   845.296] winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
[   845.296] winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
[   845.296] winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
[   845.359] winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1920 height: 1080 depth: 32
[   845.359] winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
[   845.359] winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
[   845.359] MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
[   845.359] XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
[   845.375] glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
[   845.453] (II) AIGLX: Testing pixelFormatIndex 1
[   845.531] GL_VERSION:     4.6.0 - Build 27.20.100.8190
[   845.531] GL_VENDOR:      Intel
[   845.531] GL_RENDERER:    Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
[   845.531] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
[   845.531] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_MESA_swap_control
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIS_multisample
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[   845.546] (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
[   845.546] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[   845.546] (II) 108 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
[   845.562] (II) 72 fbConfigs
[   845.562] (II) ignored pixel formats: 0 not OpenGL, 0 unknown pixel type, 36 unaccelerated
[   845.562] (II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
[   846.203] winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 960 540
[   846.203] (--) 5 mouse buttons found
[   846.203] (--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
[   846.203] (--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 7
[   846.203] (--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
[   846.203] (--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
[   846.203] Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
[   846.203] [   846.203] winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
[   846.421] winInitMultiWindowWM - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the display.
[   846.437] winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
[   846.437] winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
[   846.437] winMultiWindowXMsgProc - xcb_connect() returned and successfully opened the display.
[   846.437] winClipboardProc - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the display.
[   846.437] Using Composite redirection
[   851.250] SetupSysMenu: GetSystemMenu() failed for HWND 0x5048a
[   992.875] OS has icon alpha channel support: yes
[  1096.187] executing 'xterm -title $XWINLOGFILE -e less +F $XWINLOGFILE', pid 1282
[  1101.500] SetupSysMenu: GetSystemMenu() failed for HWND 0x80752
[  1142.750] executing 'xterm -title $XWINLOGFILE -e less +F $XWINLOGFILE', pid 1284
[  1153.953] SetupSysMenu: GetSystemMenu() failed for HWND 0x50730
[  1201.625] executing 'xterm -title $XWINLOGFILE -e less +F $XWINLOGFILE', pid 1286
```

Comment: try setting the verbose option. I believe if you set it to 5 or higher, vim will tell you what shell command it actually runs.

Comment: Thanks, Christian!  That works.  It gave `Calling shell to execute: "(ls) < /tmp/vrSTxrs/32>/tmp/vrSTxrs/33 2>&1"`. Did you want to post that as the answer?  BTW, I'm still using your [cursor highlighting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/_vbtxlld318) from years back!

Comment: @user2153235 Feel free to self answer the question with the details of what worked for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what I inferred from a too-quick perusal of the help, setting the `verbose` option to 5 lets me see the command that is issued by `vim` when shelling out.  By then, however, I had already banished the problem by upgrading all Cygwin packages and re-installing `vim`.  So I will probably never really find out what the pathology was in shelling out.

Thanks to Christian Brabandt for correcting my misconception that `verbose` wouldn't help.